# Confusion matrix plot one decimal but exact zeros

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to plot a confusion matrix that has one decimal for all values but if the value is exact zero, I would like to keep it as an exact zero rather than 0.0. How can I achieve this? In this minimal example for example I would like to keep `4.0` but instead of `0.0` I would like a `0`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay

y_true = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
y_pred = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]

disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred),
display_labels=[0, 1])

disp.plot(include_values=True, cmap='Blues', xticks_rotation='vertical',
          values_format='.1f', ax=None, colorbar=True)

plt.show()
```

I tried to pass a custom function

```
def custom_formatter(value):
    if value == 0:
        return '{:.0f}'.format(value)
    else:
        return '{:.1f}'.format(value)
```

to

```
disp.plot(include_values=True, cmap='Blues', xticks_rotation='vertical', 
          values_format=values_format, ax=None, colorbar=True)
```

but this gives the error

```
TypeError: format() argument 2 must be str, not function
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is looping + check/replace text:

```py
for iy, ix in np.ndindex(disp.text_.shape):
    txt = disp.text_[iy, ix]
    if txt.get_text() == "0.0":
        txt.set_text("0")
```

[image: Confusion matrix, but instances of 0.0 have been replaced with 0 with no decimal point.] [image: Second image of a confusion matrix but with 6 rows and columns.]